# Graph does not render as expected

Tags: java, gephi

This is the entire source code for the java file.

```
package gephifyer;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.gephi.data.attributes.api.AttributeColumn;
import org.gephi.data.attributes.api.AttributeController;
import org.gephi.data.attributes.api.AttributeModel;
import org.gephi.graph.api.DirectedGraph;
import org.gephi.graph.api.GraphController;
import org.gephi.graph.api.GraphModel;
import org.gephi.io.exporter.api.ExportController;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.Container;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.EdgeDefault;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.ImportController;
import org.gephi.io.importer.spi.FileImporter;
import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.DefaultProcessor;
import org.gephi.partition.api.Partition;
import org.gephi.partition.api.PartitionController;
import org.gephi.partition.plugin.NodeColorTransformer;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewController;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewModel;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewProperty;
import org.gephi.preview.types.DependantOriginalColor;
import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController;
import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
import org.gephi.ranking.api.Ranking;
import org.gephi.ranking.api.RankingController;
import org.gephi.ranking.plugin.transformer.AbstractSizeTransformer;
import org.gephi.statistics.plugin.Modularity;
import org.openide.util.Lookup;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.force.StepDisplacement;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.force.yifanHu.YifanHu;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.force.yifanHu.YifanHuLayout;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.openord.*;

public class Gephifyer {

    public void doStuff(String[] args)
    {
        String filename = new String();
        try{
            filename = args[0];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            System.out.println("Supply the subreddit name as the argument.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
        pc.newProject();
        Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

        ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);
        Container container;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename + ".csv");
            //File file = new File(getClass().getResource("askscience.csv").toURI());
            container = importController.importFile(file);
            container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDefault.DIRECTED);
            container.setAllowAutoNode(false); // don't create missing nodes
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Append imported data to graph api
        importController.process(container, new DefaultProcessor(), workspace);

        GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getModel();
        DirectedGraph directedGraph = graphModel.getDirectedGraph();
        // Now let's manipulate the graph api, which stores / serves graphs
        System.out.println("Nodes: " + directedGraph.getNodeCount() + "\nEdges: " + directedGraph.getEdgeCount());

        //Run OpenOrd.
        //OpenOrdLayout layout = new OpenOrdLayout(null);
        YifanHuLayout layout = new YifanHuLayout(null, new StepDisplacement(0.95f));
        layout.setGraphModel(graphModel);
        layout.resetPropertiesValues();
        layout.initAlgo();
        layout.goAlgo();
        while (layout.canAlgo()) // This is only possible because OpenOrd has a finite number of iterations.
        {
            layout.goAlgo();
        }

        AttributeModel attributemodel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(AttributeController.class).getModel();

        // Get modularity for coloring
        Modularity modularity = new Modularity();
        modularity.setUseWeight(true);
        modularity.setRandom(true);
        modularity.setResolution(1.0);
        modularity.execute(graphModel, attributemodel);
        // Partition with modularity
        AttributeColumn modcol = attributemodel.getNodeTable().getColumn(Modularity.MODULARITY_CLASS);
        PartitionController partitionController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PartitionController.class);
        Partition p = partitionController.buildPartition(modcol, directedGraph);
        NodeColorTransformer nodeColorTransformer = new NodeColorTransformer();
        nodeColorTransformer.randomizeColors(p);
        partitionController.transform(p, nodeColorTransformer);

        // Ranking
        RankingController rankingController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(RankingController.class);
        Ranking degreeRanking = rankingController.getModel().getRanking(Ranking.NODE_ELEMENT, Ranking.INDEGREE_RANKING);
        AbstractSizeTransformer sizeTransformer = (AbstractSizeTransformer) rankingController.getModel().getTransformer(Ranking.NODE_ELEMENT, org.gephi.ranking.api.Transformer.RENDERABLE_SIZE);
        sizeTransformer.setMinSize(5.0f);
        sizeTransformer.setMaxSize(40.0f);
        rankingController.transform(degreeRanking,sizeTransformer);

        // Finally, the preview model
        PreviewController previewController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PreviewController.class);
        PreviewModel previewModel = previewController.getModel();
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.SHOW_NODE_LABELS, Boolean.TRUE);
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.NODE_LABEL_COLOR, new DependantOriginalColor(Color.BLACK));
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.NODE_LABEL_FONT, previewModel.getProperties().getFontValue(PreviewProperty.NODE_LABEL_FONT).deriveFont(8));
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_CURVED, Boolean.FALSE);
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_OPACITY, 50);
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_RADIUS, 10f);
        previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.TRANSLUCENT);

        previewController.refreshPreview();

        System.out.println("starting export");
        ExportController ec = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ExportController.class);
        try{
            ec.exportFile(new File(filename + ".svg"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Gephifyer g = new Gephifyer();
        g.doStuff(args);
    }
}
```

At its heart, it's the various demos' code cobbled together to do what I want it to do.

I expect a graph that looks like [this svg file](https://gist.github.com/Skyyrunner/9660918#file-mineralporn_java-svg), but the result is [this svg file](https://gist.github.com/Skyyrunner/9660918#file-mineralporn_expected-svg). That is, the problem is that the above code yields a graph where the arrows aren't fully connected to the nodes, making it look a bit messy. I can't for my life tell where in the code that is happening, though I guess it would be in the preview model part.

Answer (score 0):

`previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_RADIUS, 10f);` sets the distance of the arrows from the node.